# eRuby - no implicit conversion of nil into String when comparing numbers in an if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eruby

I have a basic eRuby each loop

```
 <% @product_images.each do |image|%>

        <% if @counter < 4 %>

           <% p 'Im in here' %>
        <% else %>

           <% return %>
        <% end %>

          <% @counter += 1 %>
          <% p @counter %>

 <% end %>
```

Inside my loop i have an `if` statement that checks if `@counter` is `<` than `4`.

Controller code

```
def show

     productId = params[:id]

     @product_images = ProductImage.where("product_id = ?", productId)

     @counter = 0
end
```

When i run this code it should return once the counter is greater than 4 but i get an error that says `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

This is pretty straight forward code i can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong. It seems like it's breaking in the line

```
<% if @counter < 4 %>
```

Here is a picture of the error:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to limit the product images to no greater than four? If so, you should `@product_images` in the controller and then be done with all that logic in your view. (Or, perhaps, you're doing something else we can't see from the code you provide.)

Comment: @jvillian yes i'm basically building an image gallery for products, so i need to show 4 and then a 5th one which when clicked will open a modal with all the images. I guess i could create an array of 4 and then then create another array with all of them to achieve this too. Thanks for the advice going to try it out.

Comment: @jvillian What you recommended worked perfectly, if you want submit it as the answer so i can accept it. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to limit the number of `@product_images` that are rendered in your view. Instead of using `@counter`, you should simply limit the number of `@product_images` in your controller, something like:

```
def show
  @product = Product.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @product_images = @product.product_images.limit(4)
end
```

And then in your view, do something like:

```
<% @product_images.each do |image| %>
  # do stuff
<% end %>
```

This, naturally, assumes that:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :product_images
end
```

And:

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

You *could* put that logic back in the view, like:

```
<% @product.product_images.limit(4).each do |image| %>
  # do stuff
<% end %>
```

And then your `show` action could be just:

```
def show
  @product = Product.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

But, I prefer leaving it in the controller to reduce the coupling between your views and your models.